# How can I put a label on top of a PieChart legend

Tags: legending

I would like to put a legend label above a legend generated from PieChart / ChartLegends. The closest I could come is with

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3, 4},
 FrameLabel -> {"Situations", "Score"},
 PlotLabel -> "Exemple de graphique en tarte",
 ChartLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black},
 Epilog -> Text["Situations", {1.2, 0.5}]
 ]
```

but the text "situation" is out of the plot area and is only partially visible, as seen below. I use MMA 10.0
[image]

Comment: `PieChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Exemple de graphique en tarte",
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, LegendLabel -> "Situations"], BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the option `LegendAppearance`:

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Exemple de graphique en tarte", 
 ChartLegends -> {"1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
 LegendAppearance -> {LegendLabel -> Style["legend", Red, 16]}, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black}]
```

or, alternatively, use the `LegendLabel` option inside `SwatchLegend`:

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3, 4}, PlotLabel -> "Exemple de graphique en tarte", 
 ChartLegends -> SwatchLegend[{"1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
   LegendLabel -> Style["legend", Red, 16]], 
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontColor -> Black}]
```

to get

[image]